# How to prevent unencrypted file to be written to folder reserved for Gnome Encfs files?

Tags: gnome, 15.10, encfs

I use Gnome Encfs to encrypt a folder. I have it set to "Unmount when idle after 5 minutes". 
If a open a file from that folder and it stays open in a program, the file can be autosaved after 5 minutes, leaving the file unencrypted. How do I prevent this?
This has happened to me once, due to my occasional absent mindedness. I hope to get a technical way to mitigate this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to revoke write permission to the folder when it is **not** mounted.
If your program is "smart" enough to override write permissions then change ownership of the folder to, e.g. root:root.  For example if you mount your encfs in:

```
/home/user/directory
```

then do

```
sudo chown root:root /home/user/directory
sudo chmod 0700 /home/user/directory
```

Comment: The folder gets deleted after unmounting. The program re-created the folder and wrote the unencrypted file after that.

Comment: Well, then change the ownership of the folder the program is creating the folder in. This way write permissions can't be overridden.